# Reading HTTPS page with username/password authentication and ignore certifiacte

Tags: java, http, curl, https, httpurlconnection

I need to read some data from HTTPS page that has a local certificate and requires a username/password authentication.

Using "HttpURLConnection", is it possible to do username/password authentication and import the local certificate or ignore it?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try to use this. Work for me.

```
private void authenticadorRedeTendencia() {
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName(), password.toCharArray());
            }
        });
    }
```